# Logon access control by group - naming conventions?

Tags: pam, access-control

I want to implement a policy where (ldap) users are only allowed to logon to a host based on their group membership. The [pam_listfile](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-deny-allow-linux-user-group-login.html) module seems to be the most sensible way to achieve this (does anyone have better ideas?). That means I need to add a new configuration file listing the allowed groups. The suggested name in the linked article above for the file seems to be ad-hoc (where I find other references to this name, they also reference this article).

What filename should I be using to list the permitted groups?

Comment: as a side note to anyone reading this in future - note that opensshd has an AllowedGroups option - but sshd can ignore pam and this does not allow for combination rules such as GROUP1 OR GROUP2 AND GROUP3 - which can be done using multiple pam_listfile entries